# Is there a difference between $(element).find(".class").css(...) and $(this).css inside a $(element).find(".class").each() function?

Tags: jquery, backbone.js

If i want to edit CSS properties of a DOM element with a specific class using the jQuery find method, does it make a difference (in performance and browser compatibility) if i use this short way:

```
$(domobject).find(".theclass").css("color","#FFF");
```

or an each function like this:

```
$(domobject).find(".theclass").each(function() {
    $(this).css("color","#FFF");
});
```

In my case the dom-object is a backbone.js view.el element, but of course my question does not only apply to backbone.js.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: For performance: just set up a [jsperf.com](http://jsperf.com) test and see for yourself.

Comment: Browser compatibility: No, that's why you use jQuery ;). Performance: http://jsperf.com/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Performance-wise, the first snippet is [slighty faster](http://jsperf.com/jquery-explicit-each):

[image]

Internally, it does pretty much the same thing, but the code to iterate over a set of elements inside jQuery is likely to be far more optimised than what you can achieve manually with `.each`.

As others have already stated, browser compatability should be identical.

Answer (score 3):

So you want to style all your elements with the class "theclass"?

If so the [jQuery Documentation for .each()](http://api.jquery.com/each/%20%22jQuery%20Api%20for%20.each%28%29) says:

> Note: most jQuery methods that return a jQuery object also loop through the set of elements in the jQuery collection — a process known as implicit iteration. **When this occurs, it is often unnecessary to explicitly iterate with the .each() method**

As Sirko suggested you could do a performance test :) I'd prefer your first choice

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes, in this particular case i want to style them, but my question was more general - if the "direct" way (first snippet) is better/worse or different in any way than looping with the each function. With the .css() example it just was easier for me to explain ;)

Answer (score 2):

The 1st choice is better — less code, no creation of unnecessary anonymous function, no calls of this function. Both are сross-browser.
jQuery: write less, do more.